# Scaffold Item Sitecore

Tags: xm-cloud

I just tried to create a new Scaffold component but when run for example: `npm run scaffold -- MyComponent`, i receive  Cannot find module `'./scaffold-component.ts'`
Require stack:.

Any idea to fix it?
Thank you.

sxastarter@21.2.0 scaffold

> ts-node --project tsconfig.scripts.json scripts/scaffold-component.ts MyComponent

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module './scaffold-component.ts'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if `scaffold-component.ts` is present in your application under `Scripts` (`scripts/scaffold-component.ts`) folder. This scaffold file is to use for creating the new components.
Before creating a component, you must check whether the NextJs application is running properly.
Use `npm run start:connected` to run the NextJS application. If the application is running properly, please try to scaffold new component-
`npm run scaffold -- MyComponent`

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

The issue I found with this is related to the path of scaffold-component script. The path provided in sxastarter project's `package.json` is incorrect. There actually is no file called `scaffold-component.ts` within `scripts` folder. Check the folder structure below.

[image: Scripts folder structure]

### Solution

To resolve the path, update the following line within your package.json
[image]

To:

```
"scaffold": "ts-node --project tsconfig.scripts.json scripts/scaffold-component/index.ts"
```

Which now will have the correct path.

You should now be able to run `jss scaffold MyComponent` or `npm run scaffold -- MyComponent`

Hope this helps.