# Setting up Sitecore sxastarter project in Linux/Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sxa, setup, development

I use Ubuntu for development. What is the best way to set up sxastarter project for Linux development in Connected mode or Sitecore first approach? Are there any resources available that focus on Linux development in connected mode?

All resources that I can find are focused on the Windows development environment. I'm interested to know if anybody has been able to set it up correctly in linux or mac.

So far, I have

- Created a project using XMCloud deploy
- Created a starter site using "Starter template" which is a sxastarter template.

  - It was first created into github using connected
  - later the branch connected was removed
- Configured API keys, new App_Config for setting up deployment secret, `.env.local`
- Deployed the config
- created a deployment
- Run nextjs app locally in connected mode - `npm run start:connected`

### Context

It seems to load the site correctly. However, the structure of sitecore in context explorer is slightly different to tutorials I can find. For example, when trying to create a component using tutorials, the placeholder settings folder is different and doesn't have `Main`. Nor can I create a component using `npm run scaffold -- MyComponent`, as it throws error:

```bash
npm run scaffold -- MyComponent

> sxastarter@21.3.1 scaffold
> ts-node --project tsconfig.scripts.json scripts/scaffold-component.ts MyComponent

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './scaffold-component.ts'
Require stack:
- /path/to/project/projects/my-sitecore-project/src/sxastarter/scripts/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:125:19)
    at requireResolveNonCached (/path/to/project/projects/my-sitecore-project/src/sxastarter/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:549:16)
    at getProjectSearchDir (/path/to/project/projects/my-sitecore-project/src/sxastarter/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:519:40)
    at phase3 (/path/to/project/projects/my-sitecore-project/src/sxastarter/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:267:27)
    at bootstrap (/path/to/project/projects/my-sitecore-project/src/sxastarter/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:47:30)
    at main (/path/to/project/projects/my-sitecore-project/src/sxastarter/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:33:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/projects/my-sitecore-project/src/sxastarter/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:579:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/path/to/project/projects/my-sitecore-project/src/sxastarter/scripts/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.18.0
```

Which makes me wonder if the project is set up properly.

Has anybody had any luck setting a proper dev workflow in linux/Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I partially found an answer to component scaffold, which seems to be the issue with the path in package.json that comes with sxastarter. I have posted an answer to that piece here.
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/36226/13694

Besides that, I still wonder if there is a better doc on setting up the project for linux or mac